# Why Do Core Animation Types Take A String Key Path?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm confused as to why the `keyPath` is a string when animating a specific property on a `CALayer`. Would it not be better and safer just to use an enum? Just wondering as to the advantage of typing out a string literal.

Example: `let flash = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) was written in Objective C and Objective C does not have swift enums if you are thinking of using reflection as in Swift Codable and CodingKeys.

Core Animation also uses [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to detect and animate changes to your layer's properties.  This is what allows implicit animation and is why the UIView.Animation methods are able to animate your views when you make changes inside their block without you explcitily animating anything.  You change the property's value and the animation system observes that change by KVO and generates the corresponding animation for you.

Comment: Great concise answer that explains it clearly. Thank you

Comment: Great answer. Can you propose some good resources on Core Animation?

Answer (score 6):

While Josh Homann's answer is very helpful, it's also worth noting that there's no particular enum that could work in this case. `CASpringAnimation` can be applied to any property at all, not just built-in ones. Even "built-in" is misleading, because there are many built-in CALayer subclasses and they have different properties themselves. Animations don't even have to be applied to a layer (SceneKit uses them as well). If you added a custom property to a layer, and wanted to animate it with a spring animation, it would be impossible if this were an enum.

That said, you can do better than passing a string here (or even a string constant). You can use `#keyPath`:

```
let flash = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.borderColor))
```

This provides compile-time checking that this method actually is defined. This achieves much of the goal as you're looking for with an enum, while being flexible enough to handle any target and property.

In the future, hopefully, Core Animation will accept the new Swift 4 "KeyPath" types, and you'll be able to do this:

```
let flash = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: \CALayer.borderColor)
```

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation, Rob. What would an example of a non 'built-in' type be? Is there not a finite number of properties on a view that could be animated?

Comment: By non-built-in, I just mean "a custom CALayer subclass." I make these all the time. There are an unbounded number of properties on a layer that can be animated (and of course there they can be key *paths* not just simple properties). For an example, see https://github.com/rnapier/richtext-coretext/blob/master/PinchText/Classes/PinchTextLayer.m. That layer has a dictionary called `touchPointForIdentifier`. I animate the keyPath `touchPointForIdentifier.<identifier>.scale` (NSDictionary exposes all its keys as key paths). "scale" here is a property on a simple NSObject subclass (not a Layer).

Comment: For a simpler example, see https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch08-Animation/Actions/Actions/CircleLayer.m  This is a circle layer that animates its `radius` property. (It implicitly animates its radius property, so if you call `circle.radius = 4`, it'll animate that, but it's implemented with a CABasicAnimation on the keyPath "radius". )